# Open file in browser via ssh

Tags: ssh, mac, browser

I frequently produce image files on a server that I have ssh access to and want to look at them on my Mac laptop.  Currently, my process for doing that is

```
scp server:path/to/file.png .
open file.png
```

or instead of the `open` command, drag the file from Finder to my browser.  Is there a way to avoid the copy and just point the browser at the file?  I am hoping for something like

```
open ssh://server/path/to/file.png
```

or typing something similar into the address bar.

When I searched from chrome and ssh, I found ways to have an `ssh:` link open a terminal, but that is not what I am looking for.

I would prefer to have them open in Chrome, but Safari would also work. Other Mac-compatible browsers are possible but I do not currently use them.

MacOS 11.6.4 (Big Sur)
Chrome 99.0.4844.84

Chrome should be pretty much current.  Upgrading to the next major version of MacOS is not possible at the moment.